# NO POST data in Django

Tags: python, django

I am having some trouble in posting data in django. My HTML looks like following:

```
<form action="/bend_calculation" method="POST">
 <table><tbody>
<tr>
 <td><label style="display:inline-block">Pipeline Diameter (mm)</label> </td>
 <td> </td>
<td><input type="text" name="D" value=""/></td>
 </tr>

 <input style="width:10em;background-color:#6986DB" type="submit" id ="sbbtn" value="Submit"></td>
```

I am reading Django function as;

```
  request.POST.get('D')
```

But the form is returning "None". The entire program is csrf exempt!

Greatly appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should close your from with following tag:

```
</form>
```

Do you have test the following conditionnal ?

```
if request.POST:
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the `APPEND_SLASH` setting as True, which it is by default. That means that when you POST to "/bend_calculation", Django automatically redirects to "/bend_calculation/", and redirects are always GETs. You should make sure to post to "/bend_calculation/", or even better use the `{% url %}` tag to calculate the URL dynamically.